# Soma horas obtidas através de uma consulta no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT
    TIMEDIFF(
        atendimento_ticket.close_atendimento,
        atendimento_ticket.open_atendimento
    ) AS duracao
FROM
    atendimento_ticket
WHERE
    id_tec = '$id_tec'
```

Comment: Conseguir fazer o seguinte sq não está bem formatado.

SELECT SUM(duracao) FROM (SELECT TIMEDIFF( atendimento_ticket.close_atendimento, atendimento_ticket.open_atendimento ) AS duracao FROM atendimento_ticket WHERE id_tec = 5 ) as dur

Comment: `SELECT
   SUM(TIMEDIFF(
        atendimento_ticket.close_atendimento,
        atendimento_ticket.open_atendimento
    )) AS total_duracao
FROM
    atendimento_ticket
WHERE
    id_tec = '$id_tec'`